# isChecked() method always returns false for react-native screen - UIAUTOMATOR

Tags: automation, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

As mentioned in various blogs The `UiObject.isChecked()` method works for checkbox verification for property like - if it is checked already or not but it seems to be working for android native screens only, as I tried it on react-native screen in my app and it always returns `.isChecked` as false. 

I have tried with `UiObject2` class as well as `UiObject` class but it is not working!

So the problem is - `UiObject.ischecked()` is not working on react-native screens in android app. Can someone help ? or confirm if it works for you than how it is working ?

code below:

```
try {    
UiObject checkBox_toggle = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().description("toggle_checkbox"));   if (checkBox_toggle.isChecked()) {
         checkBox_toggle.click();
          }    } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
         UiObject2 checkBox_toggle = 
         mDevice.findObject(By.desc("toggle_checkbox"));
            if (checkBox_toggle.isChecked()) {
               checkBox_toggle.click(); 
             }
```

Thanks!